# How can solve the ERROR [BABEL] maximum size 500KB issue in server?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, nuxtjs

I am using NUXTJS application for an SSR page, but i am getting an error of bootstrap-vue icon size issue.

The file is hosted in AWS server and this will be the error

```
The code generator has deoptimised the styling of 
/var/www/html/my_folder/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/icons/icons.js
as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
```

[image]

What will be the issue on this ? i have added babbel in build location too..

Answer (score 13):

Try to add

`babel: { compact: true }`

below `extend(config, ctx) {},` like this

```
....
 /*
 ** You can extend webpack config here
 */
 extend(config, ctx) {},
 babel: { compact: true }
```

ref: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5627#issuecomment-668487772

Edit: edit this on nuxt.config.js file

Comment: I have added like this already ...  https://prnt.sc/u10l7p

Answer (score 7):

you can add it like this and it works,just added in your nuxt.config.js file

```
  build: {
     babel: {
      compact: true,
     },
  },
```

Comment: After I add this, when I run 'npm run build' command it doesn't build anymore. Any idea why?